# My dequeue function doesn't work properly, what is my mistake?

Tags: c

```
struct Node* Dequeue(struct Queue *queue)
{
struct Node *temp = queue->front;
if (temp == NULL)
{
    printf("Nothing to delete");
    return temp;
}
else if (temp->next == NULL)
{
    free(temp);
    queue->front = NULL;
    queue->rear = NULL;
    printf("Successfully delete.");
    return temp;
}
else
{
    queue->rear = queue->rear->next;
    free(temp);
    printf("Successfully delete.");
    return temp;
}
}
```

As I printed in the main() function the data of the deleted node, it appears to be outputting a random number, what is my mistake here? Anyone please help.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a **specific** problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

You both `free` and `return` the node. If you want to free the node, don't return it. If you want to return the node, don't free it. As it is now, you are returning a pointer to where the node was before you freed it. What use is that?

Comment: So that I could print in the main function the data that I have deleted.

Comment: @ILoveYouVirus Except you already deleted it. So it's not there anymore.

Comment: After you free it, it doesn't exist anymore... (it might, but there is no guarantee), generally the function address space is wiped following return.